# Share HTML Content on facebook

Tags: android, html, facebook

How do I share html content on facebook? What I want is to share text in tabular format on facebook. I tried sharing it as text on wall,it didnt work. Also, I tried saving it as .html and posting to facebook like we share images. It didnot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I see on google, posting raw HTML on your Facebook wall is not possible, what you can do is upload a page and reference to it on the wall with a link.

Answer (score 2):

Posting to a user's wall is done issuing a POST to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed
```

with a Facebook object of type [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/). The Facebook Post type includes these String content fields that are visible after posting:

```
description
caption
message
```

None of these fields support HTML.

Answer (score 1):

use facebook post API for this purpose...
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/
it may help u for different parameters for Facebook post.